# Java IndexOutOfBoundsException list error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

**Part of the code:**

```
List<Triangle> triangles = model.getTriangles().stream()
            .map(triangle -> triangle.rotate(orientation))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As I understand `model.getTriangles` the function gets data and constantly streams it into triangles list.
Well, the problem is I have 2 threads on my program. Main thread and extra.
If they both try to simultaneously use that part of the code it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Help.

Comment: `synchronize(model)`?

Comment: And if you run your code in a single thread only, you don't get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Without more code, I can just advise you to take a look at synchronized methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html 
It should solve your problem.

Comment: In single thread probably not. Main thread has some stuff that uses it(not my code). I have edited this code to my purposes and added separate thread for my needs. It seems they clash sometimes. IntelliJ IDEA points to this line. Googling about it gives me some vague hints about thread-safe stuff.